# complicated sql query, big database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following db tables:

BOOKS

```
book_id | date | library_id 
1       |  06  | 34
2       |  02  | 12
3       |  04  | 34
4       |  09  | 66
```

LIBRARY

```
library_id | adress | owner
1          |  "cxc" | "andf"
2          |  "mkm" | "kla"
3          |  "ass" | "pol"
4          |  "kon" | "ger"
```

PAGESLLV

```
page_id | book_id | text
4       |   4     | "YYYY ss"
3       |   1     | "FFF as"
3       |   1     | "FDER fs"
3       |   2     | "GRG xx""
```

PAGESKYK

```
page_id | book_id | text
1       |   1     | "ddadad"
2       |   3     | "xcvxcv"
1       |   3     | "adad"
2       |   2     | "ddddweg"
```

PAGESLOO

```
page_id | book_id | text
6       |   5     | "VV"
5       |   2     | "CCC"
6       |   2     | "ZZ"
7       |   3     | "AA"
```

and some information about db:

1)  every books has many pages

```
 example:

 Book with id 622 has:
 234 pages with id 45,
 120 pages with id 23,
 1 page with id 11,
 1 page with id 31,

 Book with id 322 has:
 1 page with id 67,
 1 page with id 88
```

2) Every book has one library_id

There are 9 tables named PAGE___ (where ___ is like "LLV")
any of them has around 24 million records.

Now, i need to create query to extract all books (include library adress) which contain all pages with given ids.

So, for example:

```
Book with id 622 has:
 234 pages with id 45,
 120 pages with id 88,
 1 page with id 11,
 1 page with id 23,

Book with id 13 has:
 234 pages with id 88,
 120 pages with id 23,
 1 page with id 11,
 1 page with id 15,
 2 pages with id 56,

 Book with id 322 has:
 1 page with id 23,
 1 page with id 88
```

they give me array [88,23,11,15] and i return

```
book_id | date | library_adress | library_owner | 
13      | ~~~~ | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
```

because only book with id 13 is valid.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

My sql for now:

```
'with p1 as (
    select distinct podv.Book_id, podv.Page_Id
    from PAGESLLV podv with (nolock)
    where podv.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')
    union all
    select distinct psv.Book_id, psv.Page_Id
    from PAGESXXN psv with (nolock)
    where psv.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')
    union all
    select distinct psav.Book_id, psav.Page_Id
    from PAGESTTY psav with (nolock)
    where psav.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')
    union all
    select distinct psx.Book_id, psx.Page_Id
    from PASGESPOO psx with (nolock)
    where psx.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')
    union all
    select distinct pv.Book_id, pv.Page_Id
    from PAGESMIO pv with (nolock)
    where pv.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')
    union all
    select distinct tpb.Book_id, tpb.Page_Id
    from PAGESQWW tpb with (nolock)
    where tpb.Page_Id in (' + @Ids + ')),
p2 as ( select p1.Book_id
    from p1
    group by p1.Book_id
    having COUNT(p1.Book_id) = ' + @Amount + ')
select top 1000
    r.Book_id,
    r.date,
    v.adress,
    v.owner,
    from  Books r with (nolock)
    inner join p2 with (nolock) on (r.Book_id = p2.Book_id)
    join Library v with (nolock) on (r.library_id = v.library_id)
    order by r.Book_id')
```

it works but too slow

Thanks for any help, and sorry for my english skills.

Comment: So what have you tried so far....

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1JTbQJjz
it works for now but too slow :/

Comment: Please add the RDBMS (vendor and version) and please add the ecpected output **fitting to the given sample data**!

Comment: `There are 9 tables named PAGE___` That is a really bad design. You should have one table pages and another table pagesType (or whatever) and a column on pages table fk to this new table.

Comment: It would not be complicated to migrate all the data and also you wouldn't have that huge SQL.

Comment: you should post you current sql in the question

Comment: @JorgeCampos i can't create one table named pages because table PAGELLV has many  different column than PAGEXXN etc. i wrote only column from tables wich are important for this issue

Comment: That's no problem as well, I'm sure that most of those fields could be also modeled in a better way. You can't change the database, you can't create indexes, you can't partition. I'm sorry for you, but there are no available options to help you out.

Comment: i'm only little dev in big company and i do not have any access to modify database. Only creating queries. Anyway, thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

Hi been playing around to see how well this will act in parallel.  So i believe the best approach is as follows,

```
With CTE(RealID,ID,Name) as (
select * from Table_1a
Union all
select * from Table_1b
)

select * from CTE where RealID in (1,43)
```

Where CTE in your instance is all your pages table, if you make sure that BookId is an index (probably best to cluster it) in each table, you should see quite a decent execution plan.  I've only tested with circa 140k records per table, but it does perform ok for me.